# Create a div containing an image, which has a fixed height using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just started using bootstrap.
I wanted to create a div with an image inside of a div that had a fixed height eg 30%.
I have created the div containing the image with a fixed height, but I can not understand why the width is not all the page.
And when I create a navbar below the div with the image that are not attached but it remains disconnected.
My idea was to create something like this: http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/51241.html

What I've written for the moment:
HTML code:

```
<div class="container-fluid container-image">
        <div class="row my-row" style="height:100px; width: 100%">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="content"></div>
            <div class="background" ></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">

      </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS code:

```
.my-row{
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
}
.content{
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
}
.background {
        position: absolute;
        padding-top: 200%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-image: url(image.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
body, html, .container-fluid {
     height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: 30% is *not* a fixed height, it's a relative height.

Comment: yes, I am confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you tried to size everything **but** the background-image itself.
A simple solution is at hand: in your *.background* CSS code, simply set the *background-size* to 100%. This will make sure your image always scales to the provided *col-md-X* class.

```
background-size: 100%;
```